# How do you adjust an I2C driver to handle smbus specs?

Tags: i2c, smbus

A the title says, I would just like to know how to adjust an I2C driver to handle smbus specs in general.

Answer (score 0):

The SMBus command set is automatically translated to I2C on I2C adapters, but plain I2C commands can not be handled at all on most pure SMBus adapter.

This makes it possible to use the device driver on both SMBus adapters and I2C adapters.
So it is good to use SMBus APIs instead I2C as most of the devices are compatible wo handle SMBus api calls.

Comment: A pure I2C peripheral will still need to meet the clock-stretching timeout of SMBus though, potentially requiring significant code surgery and real-time software timing. Plus there are electrical differences. My limited experience is that you may seem to get away without any adjustment but that things may start failing randomly in noisy environments and edge cases.